# Autoplay video playlist after 45 seconds of idle on website with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, autoplay

I am making a website that plays videos with html5 and javascript. There will be thumbnails of the videos and when selected the video pops up and plays and close when its over.

I am trying to figure out how to get it to auto play a playlist after 45 seconds if a video has not been selected. Is there a way to do this with javascript?

It will have to check constantly, because if someone selects a video 25 seconds in, and plays a video , when the video ends and closes it will have to check again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to start playback of a HTML5 video via JavaScript on iOS. See this from Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive
>   until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method
>   is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play
>   button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.
>
> This plays the movie:

```
<input type="button" value="Play" onClick="document.myMovie.play()">
```

> This does nothing on iOS:

```
<body onLoad="document.myMovie.play()">
```

Here is link to Safari guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1